# Turn off var css and return to higher style

Tags: css

I have this CSS

```
div {
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid blue; 
  color:  var(--test, ?);
}
```

If I do not have value `--test` I want the style to apply `red`, but, I cannot do something like this:

```
div {
    color: red;
    border: 1px solid blue; 
    color:  var(--test, red);  
}
```

What other options are there?

Comment: why can't you do something like `var(default, fallback)`? Is it a constrain? Otherwise, it should work: if --test is not found, red would be used. I believe `var(--test, ?)` should be `var(--test)`.

Comment: @DaemonPainter because he want the red defined above

Comment: basically you have no option. In all the cases, the last color will be used and even if the value is invalid inside, it will get defaulted to initial or inherit